# List<Object> not accepting lists with mutiple other generic data types

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method as follows.

```
 public Map<String,List<Object>> getFFF(){
    Map<String,List<Object>> p= new HashMap<>();
    List<BigDecimal> x= new ArrayList<>();
    x.add(0.43443434344);
    x.add(0.43443434343);
    
    p.put("FFF",x);//getting compile error at this line
    
    return p
    
    }
```

I am getting compile error at the line 6 on 2nd parameter x. It says

```
Required type:
List
<Object>
Provided:
List
<BigDecimal>
```

I was expecting `List<Object>` to accept all List types. I want to add `List<String>`, and `List<long>` as well to the `List<Object>`. Basically, I want the Method return type as a List to accept all argument types. Any other way I can use to do so? I am new to Java hence I wanted some clarity on this. Can't I have a generic List that will accept all List types, whether String, Float, Long, or any data type?

Comment: Please share the complete and literal error message.

Comment: Hint: what would you expect `p.get("FFF").add("This is a string")` to do? That should work, right, because `p.get("FFF")` returns a `List<Object>`. But then what do you expect `x.get(2)` to return, given that it finds a string instead of a `BigDecimal`? (Basically a `List<Object>` is "a list that can contain anything" - whereas a `List<BigDecimal>` is "a list that can contain BigDecimal references" - that's not the same thing.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: In short: Even if `BigDecimal` is a subtype of `Object`, the type `List<BigDecimal>` is _not_ a subtype of `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of [Contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), and is by design. Here's an example that shows why this is forbidden:

```
public ArrayList<Object> transmutate(ArrayList<BigDecimal> input) {
    // Just return the input, but as ArrayList<Object>.
    // This is a forbidden function that will give the error you saw.
    return input;
}

// Create a BigDecimal array list.
ArrayList<BigDecimal> x = new ArrayList<>();
x.add(0.43443434344);
x.add(0.43443434343);

// Use the forbidden function to transform it into ArrayList<Object>.
ArrayList<Object> y = transmutate(x);
// Should be allowed, because y is a list of objects.
y.add("string");

// However, because x=y...
x.get(2)
// Would print "string", but it's supposed to be a list of BigDecimal!
```

The method signature you're looking for is probably using [Generic Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> transmutate(ArrayList<? super T>) input) {
```

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use wildcards in return types, only in method parameters. So, `ArrayList<T> transmutate(ArrayList<? super T>)` would be better (and no less generic). That said, the only change necessary to OP's code is to use `List<Object> x` instead of `List<BigDecimal>`.